# Is it possible to add data members dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I'm wondering if its possible to add new class data members at run-time in PHP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

```
$prop = 'newname';
$obj->$prop = 42;
```

will do the same thing as:

```
$obj->newname = 42;
```

Either one will add "newname" as a property in $obj if it does not yet exist.

Answer (score 2):

It is. You can add public members are run time with no additional code, and can affect protected/private members using the magical overloading methods __get() / __set(). See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) for more details.