# PHP append data to array object

Tags: php, arrays, object

In PHP I have an array `$test`. Running `var_dump($test)` looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (6) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(45) "Lorem"
    ["title"]=>
    string(96) "Lorem ipsum"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(41) "Ipsum"
    ["title"]=>
    string(86) "Dolor sit amet"
  }
}
```

Now I need to add another field (`url`) to the `$test` objects so it looks like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (6) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(45) "Lorem"
    ["title"]=>
    string(96) "Lorem ipsum"
    ["url"]=>
    string(86) "http://www.google.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(41) "Ipsum"
    ["title"]=>
    string(86) "Dolor sit amet"
    ["url"]=>
    string(86) "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
  }
}
```

I've tried `foreach()` and `$test->append('xxxxxxxx');`, but am getting errors. Shouldn't this be real easy to do? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Replace append with suggestion from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164395/is-it-possible-to-add-data-members-dynamically-in-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close:

```
foreach( $test as $t ) {
    $t->url = "http://www.example.com";
}
```

It looks like you're trying to use [`append()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.append.php) (a method of [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.append.php)) when you're really dealing with a [`stdClass object`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).

Comment: @Whymarrh Working on it ;)

Comment: as you see I dont know lots about array objects. your answer works! thanks for that! but I dont understand anything with this "It looks like you're trying to use append() (a method of ArrayObject) when you're really dealing with a stdClass object." yes I've tried to use append and yes it is a method of ArrayObject. how could I have done it to work it that way?

Comment: @caramba `ArrayObject::append()` only works on instances of `ArrayObject` and only takes a value, so for your case you wouldn't really want to use it since you are dealing with an `Array` containing `stdClass` objects and you also need to define a property (`url`).

Answer (score 1):

Append is for appending an entire object to another object. Just use normal object referencing (obj->value) to assign a url

---

```
$objectOne = new \stdClass();
$objectOne->name = 'Lorem';
$objectOne->title = 'Lorem ipsum';

$objectTwo = new \stdClass();
$objectTwo->name = 'Ipsum';
$objectTwo->title = 'Dolor sit amet';

$test = array(
    0 => $objectOne,
    1 => $objectTwo
);

$urls = array(
    0 => 'http://www.google.com',
    1 => 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
);

$i = 0;
foreach ($test as $site) {
  // Add url from urls array to object
  $site->url = $urls[$i];

  $i++;
}

var_dump($test);
```

---

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Lorem"
    ["title"]=>
    string(11) "Lorem ipsum"
    ["url"]=>
    string(21) "http://www.google.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Ipsum"
    ["title"]=>
    string(14) "Dolor sit amet"
    ["url"]=>
    string(28) "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: The counter inside the `foreach` could be better written using a simple `for` loop instead, especially since `$test` and `$urls` are the same length. You also don't need to specify your indexes on your arrays, nor do you even need `$result`.

Comment: @AndréDion: But we do not know how he adds the urls, this was just a quick mockup as an example ^^ Im guessing he has some kind of query that checks for urls for each title, or something.